# Derivative of the quotient of 2 elliptic integrals of the first kind

Tags: calculus, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

$$C=\frac{K\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}}\right)}{K\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)}$$

where $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

I need to differentiate $C$ w.r.t. to $a$.

This occurs in a formula to calculate the capacitance of an interdigitated sensor.  $a$ is the gap between the electrodes and I want to optimise the capacitance based on the size of this gap.

I'm guessing its too simple to let the derivative cancel the integral and I am left with the quotient of moduli above?

Comment: It should be doable using the quotient rule and the chain rule, together with the formula for $K'(k)$ in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426257/derivative-of-the-elliptic-integral-of-the-first-kind).

Comment: Voted to close as Possible duplicate of [Derivative of the elliptic integral of the first kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426257/derivative-of-the-elliptic-integral-of-the-first-kind), since the question becomes elementary once you know $K'(a)$