# Requesting clarification of Galois' last letter

Tags: galois-theory, elliptic-integrals

I am reading Galois' last letter to Auguste Chevalier before the infamous duel.

https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/004/10/0093-0100

What is the notation H' for a group H supposed to represent here? Later in the letter he uses the word "differentials". Surely these are not the same differentials from Calculus? And yet later, integrals are introduced. How do I make sense of these connections?
How to make sense of what he means by "modular equation" and a sine function being related to permutations?
What result of Legendre is he referencing on the 7th page for $\frac{\pi}{2}? I googled and found nothing of the sort.

Edit: I seem to have found the result referenced https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm it is Gauss-Legendre
[Derivative of the elliptic integral of the first kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426257/derivative-of-the-elliptic-integral-of-the-first-kind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Regarding the $T', S'$ notation, Galois is talking about the decomposition of a group $G$ into left resp. right cosets with respect to a subgroup $H$. The notation $H, HS, HS', \dots$ is meant to indicate the list of cosets, so $S, S', \dots$ is meant to indicate some collection of elements of $G$ belonging to different cosets. It is a little confusing that he capitalizes them but with enough context it's basically clear what he means. So that stuff about proper decompositions is referring to when $H$ is normal.
2. This is not my area, but I think the bit about modular equations is referring to the use of the [$j$-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#A_construction_with_an_elliptic_modular_function) to construct polynomials with Galois group $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. I'm not sure what he means by "sine of the amplitude..." here but it could be referring to the [elliptic sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions).
3. This is *extremely* not my area, but yes, he means differentials and integrals in the calculus sense. I believe this bit is referring to a circle of ideas involving [hyperelliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_the_first_kind), [periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_(algebraic_geometry)), and [abelian varieties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_variety#Abelian_functions), but I'm not familiar enough with this stuff to say more.